# Embedded Java DB from within Felix?

Tags: java, database, apache-felix

I assume there's a way to use an embedded Java DB instance within a standalone Felix 4.0.2 OSGi box. However I can't seem to find any clues as to how I should setup the whole thing: What implementation bundles should I use? How should I set it up?

I tried quite a few things, including getting the dedicated bundles from a glassfich 3.1.2 install, but whatever I do no persistence manager is registered by the framework to provide my app with.

My code otherwise follows all academical precepts, with a a ServiceTracker being registered to find out about EntityManagerFactory registrations, but none is found...
 Here's my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="com.julianware.toolbox.logbacktracker.pu"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- mapping-file>META-INF/maintenance_orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/vehicle_orm.xml</mapping-file -->

    <class>com.julianware.toolbox.logbacktracker.pu.LoggerEvent</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:database;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="felix" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="felix" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And my Activator's start() method:

```
public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Filter filter = context.createFilter(String.format("(&(%s=%s)(%s=%s))",
        OBJECTCLASS, EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(),
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.JPA_UNIT_NAME, "com.julianware.toolbox.logbacktracker.pu")
    ); 
    entityManagerFactoryTracker = new ServiceTracker(context, filter,  new ServiceTrackerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {}

        @Override
        public void modifiedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {}

        @Override
        public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
            logger.debug("Found Entity Manager Service reference.");
            entityManagerFactory = (EntityManagerFactory) context.getService(reference);
            return entityManagerFactory;
        }
    });
    entityManagerFactoryTracker.open();

}
```

Last, I'm on JDK 7. Java DB implementation is that of the jdk install.
Does anyone know anything?

Mighty thanks.
Julian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could try Derby from Maven Central. It should contain the correct OSGi meta data.

Comment: Thanks. But there's still something missing. The EMF service tracker still doesn't come up with any relevant service...